# jQuery. Как передать элемент в setTimeout

Tags: jquery

Подписываюсь на событие `click` для всех кнопок с классом `btn`.
Нужно, чтобы при клике ***нажатая*** кнопка становилась неактивной, а через 3 секунды становилась обратно активной.

```js
$(function() {
    $(".btn").each(function() {
        $(this).on("click", function() {
            $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
            }, 3000);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Add"/>
```

Так кнопка становится неактивной, но не срабатывает функция внутри setTimeout, точнее она вроде срабатывает, но она не понимает, что за элемент $(this).

*При этом ошибок в консоли нет.*

Собственно как быть?

Так работает, но этот вариант не устраивает

```js
$(function() {
    $(".btn").each(function() {
        $(this).on("click", function() {
            $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".btn").removeAttr("disabled");
            }, 3000);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Add"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".btn").each(function() {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
        var that = $(this);
        that.attr("disabled", "true");
        setTimeout(function() {
            that.removeAttr("disabled");
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

Но зачем цикл?

```
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
    var that = $(this);
    that.attr("disabled", "true");
    setTimeout(function() {
        that.removeAttr("disabled");
    }, 3000);
});
```

или

```
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
    }.bind(this), 3000);
});
```

Comment: ну цикл для того, чтобы подписаться на все кнопки

Comment: а еще вопрос, как сделать чтобы этот код не лочил работу дополнительных скриптов, которые отрабатывают после клика на кнопку (стандартные ASP.NET MVC валидаторы)? они перестали отрабатывать

Comment: @tCode - "Объяснитесь, сэр!" *код ... лочил работу* - что это значит?

Comment: написал не разобравишсь, задал отдельно вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614501

Answer (score 2):

Например, использовать переменную

```
$(".btn").each(function() {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
        var self = $(this);
        self.attr("disabled", "true"); 

        setTimeout(function() {
            self.removeAttr("disabled");
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```