# Почему JS код блокирует submit

Tags: html, jquery

Есть форма на ASP.NET MVC.
На форме выводится модель, у свойств которых есть определенные атрибуты стандартной валидации `[Required]`
При `submit` формы срабатывает валидатор из стандартных библиотек:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

При добавлении на страницу скрипта, который при нажатии на кнопку `submit` лочит её, а потом через 2 секунды делает активной, не происходит `submit` формы, сам скрипт лока\анлока работает как надо, в чем проблема? Что нужно добавить в этот скрипт, чтобы `submit` успешно отрабатывал?

```
$(function() {
    $(".btn").each(function() {
        $(this).on("click", function () {
            var e = $(this);
            e.attr("disabled", "disabled");
            setTimeout(function() {
                e.removeAttr("disabled");
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Вы блокируете кнопку перед отправкой формы.

Поставьте небольшой таймаут, чтобы заблокировать кнопку с небольшой задержкой:

И да, `each` не нужен

```
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
  var e = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
     e.attr("disabled", "disabled");
  },10);
  setTimeout(function() {
    e.removeAttr("disabled");
  }, 2000);

});
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло